# Accessing lists in a list with smbinning.gen() in a loop

Tags: r, list, loops, machine-learning, supervised-learning

Basically I'm trying to automate a scoring modeling workflow, and encountered a problem with inputting the results from `smbinning()` that are generated by a loop and hence recorded in a list. The result itself is a list, so I have a bunch of lists in a list. Problems arise when I'm trying to add the results (buckets for continuous variables) into a data frame. I just find it impossible to feed the syntax required to dive into the levels of the list. I tried work my way around this by referencing the column numbers and just trying to pass on the respective list names from the loop. Error I'm getting is:

> Error in [.data.frame (df, , col_id) : undefined columns selected.

My code is as follows:

```
colcnt <- ncol(e_mod)
bucket_resultlist <- list()
for (i in 2:colcnt) {
    #curvar = paste0('z', i)
    curresult = smbinning(df = e_mod, y = "Bankrupt", x = colnames(e_mod)[i], p = 0.05)
    bucket_resultlist[[paste0('Bin_Result_', colnames(e_mod)[i])]] = curresult #paste0('binresult', colnames(e)[i]) = curresult 
}

e_mod2 = e_mod

for (i in 1:length(bucket_resultlist_trunc)) {
e_mod2 = smbinning.genCUSTOM(e_mod, bucket_resultlist_trunc[[i]] , chrname = i)
}
```

I've even tried to define a customer version of the `smbinning.gen()` function to allow for this, as in the standard form it just tries to concatenate `$ivtable` to the list reference, but I need to be able to skip one level from this generated list and then run the `smbinning.gen()` for each respective list in that list. Here's the custom code and the original definitions commented out:

```
smbinning.genCUSTOM = function(df, ivout, chrname = "NewChar") {
    df = cbind(df, tmpname = NA)
    ncol = ncol(df)
    col_id = paste0(ivout, '[[6]]', collapse = NULL) # Original: ivout$col_id
    # Updated 20160130
    b = paste0(ivout, '[[4]]', collapse = NULL) # Original: ivout$bands
    df[, ncol][is.na(df[, col_id])] = 0 # Missing
    df[, ncol][df[, col_id] <= b[2]] = 1 # First valid
    # Loop goes from 2 to length(b)-2 if more than 1 cutpoint
    if (length(b) > 3) {
        for (i in 2:(length(b) - 2)) {
            df[, ncol][df[, col_id] > b[i] & df[, col_id] <= b[i + 1]] = i
        }
    }
    df[, ncol][df[, col_id] > b[length(b) - 1]] = length(b) - 1 # Last
    df[, ncol] = as.factor(df[, ncol]) # Convert to factor for modeling
    blab = c(paste("01 <=", b[2]))
    if (length(b) > 3) {
        for (i in 3:(length(b) - 1)) {
            blab = c(blab, paste(sprintf("%02d", i - 1), "<=", b[i]))
        }
    } else { i = 2 }
    blab = c(blab, paste(sprintf("%02d", i), ">", b[length(b) - 1]))

    # Are there ANY missing values
    # any(is.na(df[,col_id]))

    if (any(is.na(df[, col_id]))) {
        blab = c("00 Miss", blab)
    }
    df[, ncol] = factor(df[, ncol], labels = blab)

    names(df)[names(df) == "tmpname"] = chrname
    return(df)
}
```

All help is much appreciated!

Here's the list structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYau2.png

This is also posted in the Data Science section, but this only had 5 views during the whole of today

Comment: I think that the problem lies most likely in passing the arguments correctly into the `smbinning.genCUSTOM()` -function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stackoverflow for being my yellow rubber duck. The fix was to change the way of passing in the arguments:

`smbinning.genCUSTOM = function(df, ivout, chrname = "NewChar") {
    df = cbind(df, tmpname = NA)
    ncol = ncol(df)
    col_id = ivout[[6]] # paste0(ivout, '[[6]]', collapse = NULL) # Original: ivout$col_id
    # Updated 20160130
    b = ivout[[4]] # paste0(ivout, '[[4]]', collapse = NULL) # Original: ivout$bands`

And to refer the new df `e_mod2` instead of `e_mod`
`for (i in 1:length(bucket_resultlist_trunc)) {
e_mod2 = smbinning.genCUSTOM(e_mod2, bucket_resultlist_trunc[[i]] , chrname = i)
}`